# Tmux not filling terminal on fullscreen

Tags: debian, kali-linux, tmux

I have had this issue for quite some time, whenever I maximize the command terminal window, tmux does not fill the entire screen (has a margin on edges and bottom) as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I recently switched from `gnome` to `xfce` and now this issue is occuring even when the window is not maximized.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with your terminal rather than tmux - your font does not evenly divide until the size of the screen (once any window borders and scrollbars etc are taken off) so the terminal leaves the empty space blank. Try a different font, a different font size, or a different terminal.